# Creating Schemas with field constraints in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 using Core Service

Tags: tridion

I am working on Schema creation using Core Service 2011 in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

I just wanted to know whether it is possible to create a custom data type (or in fact a validator for a Schema field content) using the Core Services.

For example: I want to create a Schema field with the following details:

- Name: `bodyparagraphtext`
- Type: `text` with length 10 characters

Can anyone share some ideas on it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comment in response to Mihai's answer suggests what you want is a new schema field type. Tridion schemas support the following field types:

- Text fields
- Number fields
- Date fields
- Embedded Schemas
- External links
- Multimedia links
- Component links

As far as I know, adding to this list is not possible.

Why do you need a new field type? Perhaps with some more detail we can help you find the right solution.

Without knowing more, all I can think of is Application Data. This is a new Tridion 2011 feature that allows you to set custom data against any Tridion item, but this data will not be visible in the Tridion GUI. It can only be set and read using the API.

More details can be found [here](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/appdata.aspx) and [here](http://tridionfanboy.wordpress.com/category/sdl-tridion/2011/core-service-2011/).

If you don't think this will help you, please provide some more information on the reason for this requirement.

Comment: How will Application Data help in this respect, Dave? I don't see it.

Comment: Well, I dont understand Muzimil's requirements really, which is why I asked for more detail. But using Application data he could store additional information about a component based on a certain schema? It looks like he's looking for a way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the Live Documentation Portal, under publication `SDL Tridion 2011 SP1`, section `Implementing Content Manager features / Schemas / Constraining field content` (link [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=schema%2520constraints&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1333955571156&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_A0CA4F22FF3E4D2AA8D2320B7F30465B&query=&scope=&filename=Schema_ConstrainingFieldContent.xml&docid=concept_A0CA4F22FF3E4D2AA8D2320B7F30465B&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=)).

I think what you are looking for is a `minLength` / `maxLength` facets or maybe even a Regular Expression `pattern`.

When creating the Schema with Core Service, all you need to do is insert those XML nodes into the Schema `Content` node.

Comment: My aim is not regarding minimum lenght and maximum lenght. I want to create a data type just like built in field type such as text, date, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
I will clearly explain the requirement. 
I want to create a custom field type just like Text, Number,Date etc types. 
Say I want to create a field type as "ABCD" with some custom requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Tridion's own schema implementation uses [XSD appinfo annotations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cAnnotations) to layer richer functionality over basic datatypes. For example, different user interface options are controlled this way. In principle, this isn't part of Xml Schema *validation* but you could add your own annotations to control your own validation code, say in the events system and in a GUI extension.

I've just checked, and if you add your own annotations, Tridion will store them correctly. Adding such annotations doesn't appear to prevent the schema being treated as a Tridion web schema (with full user interface support), which is good, otherwise you'd have to build everything yourself. Tridion uses its own namespace for its annotation data, so if you put your own annotations into your own namespace, there should be no confusion.

Of course, any schema that Tridion will accept can be created via the core service, but in the first instance, I'd suggest creating the schema manually, and then working with code to consume the annotations and implement your richer functionality.